# TableView to detailview : Display Image and description in DetailView iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, uiviewcontroller, imageview, tableview

I explain my problem.
I have my RootController, and my DetailController.
I'd like to make a Cook Lesson.
On my rootcontroller, this is it : http://www.noelshack.com/2012-38-1348330181-rootview.png
I'd like when a row is selected my detailcontroller is like this : http://www.noelshack.com/2012-38-1348330163-detailview.png

So, Description and Image Change depending on the row selected.
How that can be doing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, your Cook Lesson is represented by some model object in your application's architecture.  In that case, your detail view controller needs to have a property that refers to the instance of the model object represented by the row of the table view in your `RootController`.  When you instantiate the detail view controller, the `RootController` will provide the instance of your model object (let's call it `Recipe`) to the `DetailController`, e.g.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CookLesson *lesson = [lessons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    DetailController *detailController = [[DetailController alloc] initWithNibName:"your-nib-name" bundle:nil];
    detailController.lesson = lesson;
    // push the controller on the nav stack, etc.
}
```